# Pyyaml dump does not produce anchors for the same objects

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I was experimenting a bit with PyYaml and I wanted to have a reference to a value appearing previously in the yaml. To give an example:

```
import yaml
a=25
dict_to_dump={'a':a,'b':a}
yaml.dump(dict_to_dump)
```

from what I understood from the specifications pyyaml should be adding an anchor to each object that has already been encountered. In my case, I would expect to have in the yaml file:

```
a:&id 25
b:*id
```

as the objects passed are exactly the same but instead, I find:

```
a:25
b:25
```

how can I obtain the desired behaviour?

Comment: Firstly, how are you importing `pyyaml` successfully ? Then what it dumped is exactly what is in your dict, which part of the pyyaml documentation made you think you'd be getting references and anchors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your expectation is incorrect. What you could expect is

```
a: &id 25
b: *id
```

with a space after the value indicator (`:`).

You also will need to do `yaml.dump(dict_to_dump, sys.stdout)` to get any output from your program, and what
you indicate is not what you get (it again is missing spaces after the value indicator).

---

You normally only get an alias if you have two objects `a` and `b` with the same value for `id(a)` and `id(b)`.
Simple objects like integers and strings (that are reused from a pool) have the same `id()` even if assigned
in different places in the source. Variable structures like a `dict` or `list`, or instances of Python classes
do not usually have the same `id()`.

PyYAML does know about this and handles some types of objects different even if the `id()` is the same.

```py
import sys
import yaml
import datetime

a = 25
b = 25
c = 'some string specified twice in the source'
d = 'some string specified twice in the source'
e = datetime.date(2023, 1, 11)
f = datetime.date(2023, 1, 11)

print('a-b', id(a) == id(b))
print('c-d', id(c) == id(d))
print('e-f', id(e) == id(f))
print('=====')

dict_to_dump = dict(e=e, x=e, f=f)
yaml.dump(dict_to_dump, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a-b True
c-d True
e-f False
=====
e: &id001 2023-01-11
f: 2023-01-11
x: *id001
```

If you want to get the expected output, you have to make a Python class `Int` that behaves like an integer.
And then when you do `a = Int(25)` you will get your anchor and alias.

This is what my library `ruamel.yaml` does, when loading in the default round-trip mode, it also preserves the
actual anchor/alias used:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a: &my_special_id 25
b: *my_special_id
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(f'{data["a"] * 4  =}')
print(f'{data["b"] + 75 =}')
print('=====')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
data["a"] * 4  =100
data["b"] + 75 =100
=====
a: &my_special_id 25
b: *my_special_id
```

To create `data` from scratch is also possible

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

Int = ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt

a = Int(25, anchor='id')
data = dict(a=a, b=a)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives what you expected in the first place:

```
a: &id 25
b: *id
```

Comment: Thank you your answer gives me some extra information which is very useful.